# Counting first occurence of consecutive values that pass criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example data below I am trying to set up a counter that will return the number of consecutive, negative values, but only counting the first occurence.

```
32 19 4 293 -30 -2 -5 -25 29 58 74 -90 -73 -62
```

I would like the function to return 4 in this case (Counting consecutive negative values from -30 to -25 and completely ignoring values from -90 to -62)

I got as far as getting the index of the first negative value, but I don't know how to count the consecutive values from there. Can somebody help, please?

EDIT:

So far I have the below formula:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(R3:EQ3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(R3:EQ3<0,),0)),"<0")
```

To explain this using the original example:

This formula finds the first negative value in this range which is -30 and then returns index of that value. Countif then goes to that index and checks if it's negative and counts it if it is. This formula, however will not count -2, -5 and -25 that come after that and it currently always returns 1.

I need it to find the -30, count it and then count any other negative values that some **straight** after.

The below shows which values I would like to count in the example range.

```
 N  N N   N   Y  Y  Y   Y  N  N  N   N   N   N
32 19 4 293 -30 -2 -5 -25 29 58 74 -90 -73 -62
           This is counted       This is ignored
```

Comment: So you want to count unique values?  Counting to 1 isn't really counting.  :-)   Where is this data located? Please show what you have tried.  It sounds like this is simply a job for "remove duplicates" or a "pivot table", although there are several other ways like "countif" or "find".

Comment: Hi, sorry if my explanation wasn't helpful. I want to find the first negative value (in this case -30) and then from there count any negative values that come after that. So, counting -30, -2, -5 and -25 = 4. The next value is 29 which is positive, so that's job done and the function should return 4. I don't care about any other negative values that come after that

Comment: Please include your formula attempts as an [edit] to your question. Explain what isn't working.

Comment: I have edited my question and tried to make it as clear as possible. Sorry, I don't know how to explain it any better.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 2016 64bit

Comment: @fejk understandable, there are plenty of picky rules to learn about posting on this site. :-)  Check out "[ask]" and **how to create a [mcve]** as well as what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].  Also, see [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your data set does not have it's first instance of negative values ending in Column `XFD` (the last column), you can use this array formula:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(TRUE,1:1<0,0)):INDEX(1:1,1,16384)>=0,0)-1
```

> Change the row reference in the formula to the row you want to test.
>
> This formula cannot be entered in the same row as the data being examined, without modification, else you will get a circular reference error
>
> To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: Works great, thank you. To get this to work in the same row I have changed the ranges to go from S:XFD (Column S in my case, can be any column) and I had to change 16384 to 16000, because otherwise the formula was #REFing. Just in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: @fejk Glad to hear it is working.  And that column argument, for a range starting at other than column A, does need to be reduced.  In your case, the maximum value would be `COLUMNS(S1:XFD1)` = `16366`.  In other words, it is the number of columns in the resultant array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function consec(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range, StartCount As Boolean
    consec = 0
    StartCount = False
    For Each r In rng
        If StartCount Then
            If r.Value < 0 Then
                consec = consec + 1
            Else
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            If r.Value < 0 Then
                StartCount = True
                consec = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

=consec(A1:Z1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

Same as Ron's formula I guess but here's little explanation

Considering that your data is in cells A1:O1 and you have some positive values either midway or at the end of your range then this array formula will work.

> =MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TRUE,A1:O1<0,0),4)&":O1")>0,0)-1

**MATCH(TRUE,A1:O1<0,0)** - We are trying to find the first negative number's position in the list.

The outer MATCH is looking for a positive number which comes after the first negative number.

i.e. The counting starts from the negative to positive , if the first positive numbers comes after 2 consecutive negative values then it will return 3.(that's why minus 1 is needed at the end.)

I hope it helps!